# How to customize an errors with Fastify, Ajv and Schema?

Tags: javascript, fastify, ajv

How can I customize an errors with Fastify, Ajv and Scheme? I need to format by:

```
{
    "message": "Bad request",
    "path": "/account/register",
    "status": 400,
    "timestamp": 1697094987,
    "errors": [
      { "key": "email", "value": "This value is not a valid email address."
    ]
}
```

When I try to:

```
const routes = async (app: Application) => {
  app.post('/accounts/register', { schema }, async (req: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
    reply.code(200);
  });
};
```

I get an error with the following format:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "code": "FST_ERR_VALIDATION",
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "body must have required property 'email'"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need you can change the response error's `message` by setting the [`schemaErrorFormatter`](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization/#schemaerrorformatter).

Nevertheless, you will not change the error output format.

Do change the output format you must:

- enable the AJV `allErrors` config. Note that [it is considered insecure](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization/#validator-compiler)
- customize the Fastify error handler

```js
const app = require('fastify')({
  logger: true,
  ajv: {
    customOptions: {
      allErrors: true
    }
  }
})

app.setErrorHandler(function (error, request, reply) {
  if (error.validation) {
    return reply.status(400).send({
      message: 'Bad request',
      path: request.url,
      status: 400,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      errors: error.validation.map(err => ({
        key: err.params?.missingProperty || err.dataPath,
        value: err.message
      }))
    })
  }

  reply.status(500).send(error)
})

const schema = {
  body: {
    type: 'object',
    required: ['name', 'age'],
    properties: {
      name: { type: 'string' },
      age: { type: 'number' }
    }
  }
}

app.post('/', { schema }, async (request, reply) => {
  return request.body
})

app.listen({ port: 8080 })
```

Will produce this output:

```json
{
  "message": "Bad request",
  "path": "/",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1697372490243,
  "errors": [
    {
      "key": "name",
      "value": "must have required property 'name'"
    },
    {
      "key": "age",
      "value": "must have required property 'age'"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: which fastify version r u using? In v4.18.0 there is no such property  `err.dataPath`. here is the validationError object `interface ValidationResult {
    keyword: string;
    instancePath: string;
    schemaPath: string;
    params: Record<string, string | string[]>;
    message?: string;
  }`

Comment: Typescript is always a step behind

Comment: `https://replit.com/@MustakimKhondak/fastify#index.js` check. if I pass a string as age no key is returned as err.dataPath not available.